# Strange thing happens with append

Tags: python

Why does the following code make a equal to "None":

```
a = [1]
a = a.append(0) if len(a) == 1 else a
```

This happens in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: `append` modifies `a` in place and returns `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append()` does not return a value.  Just do this:

```
a = [1]
if len(a) == 1:
    a.append(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It just so happens that `list.append` does not return the list. It mutates it and returns nothing (`None`).

In your case, `a = a +[0] if len(a) == 1 else a` would work. But the following is simpler: `if len(a) == 1: a.append(0)`.